# HttpURLConnection android contentLength = -1

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get data with help of a php script. I'm using for that an HttpURLConnection and GET method. The wierd thing here is that the probleme only occurs for android. I just tried it on eclipse for java and it worked perfectly. It also used to work while I was on my localhost. No that I'm trying to get the data from a online server, it's not working anymore, neither on the emulator nor the device.

Here's the function :

```
public static JSONArray getData(String scriptName)  {

    int responseCode = -1;
    JSONArray jsr = null;

    try {
        URL feedURL = new URL(BASE_URL + scriptName + ".php");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) feedURL.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000/* milliseconds */);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();

        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
            char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
            reader.read(charArray);
            String responseData = new String(charArray);

            jsr = new JSONArray(responseData);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(UnBunkerApplication.DEBUG_TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return jsr;
}
```

The generated error is that the connection.getContentLength() returns -1. So the line "new char[contentLength] is caught by the catch bloc.
The BASE_URL constant is the online url folder containing the scripts. When it was poiting to localhost, everything was fine.

Here's the method call :

```
public static void fillUsersListFromDataBase() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONArray dataJSON = DataBase.getData("getAllUsers");
            User.fillUsers(dataJSON);
        }

    });

    t.start();

    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here are the permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Any thoughts ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you catch the error and log it so that you can examine the connection creation error if any?

Comment: Well, there is no connection error visible.. responseCode == 200. Here's the log : 1542-1564/be.simongenin.unbunker E/UnBunkerDebug﹕ Error : -1.

Answer (score 0):

`connection.getContentLength()` is not a reliable way to find out the number of bytes that are in the response stream. The reasons for this are:

1. The response could be zipped/gzipped.
2. The response could be using `Tranfer-Encoding: chunked` header which is typical for HTTP/1.1 responses.
3. It looks like you're assuming that 1 byte = 1 char and creating a character array with the number of bytes. This will not always be true given that your server could be sending multiple byte characters (such as utf-8)

In both cases, the best approach is to read the stream until it gets exhausted.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
}
processJson(sb.toString());
```